# Why is SpringSource Tool Suite (STS) so slow? And how can I fix it?

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, spring-ide

I've been running STS 2.3.2 on a MacBook Pro for a few days now. I'm finding the performance to be significantly slower than any other build of Eclipse I've used. For example, switching from one tab to another can take up to 4 seconds.

I tried turning off much of the validation, and increasing the memory, but it's not making a difference.

Are others having similar experiences?

Comment: Are you using any of the STS-specific features?

Comment: So far, only the Spring XML configuration validation and auto-complete. Those are nice-to-have features, but not critical, seeing as how I've lived without them for several years.

Answer (score 32):

I had the same problem on a MacBook Pro i7. Switching editors or views was painfully slow. Solved it by turning off Spring validators that I didn't need. Go to:

SpringSource Tool Suite -> Preferences -> Spring -> Project Validators

Specifically, I deselected all validators except for Spring Validator, Beans Validator and STS Bean Validator.

Comment: The given answer by @https://stackoverflow.com/users/464249/michael-collins is 10 years older, as its 2019 now!!!.The same feature is not available in Spring Tool Suite  4.4.1, can you provide any solutions for this versions please...

Comment: @prasad_21 The process is the same, the wording has just changed. Window -> Preferences -> Spring -> Validation will take you to where you need to go

Answer (score 20):

I would also suggest turning off automatic build feature. Uncheck Project -> Build Automatically. Combined with Michael's suggestions it made difference for me.

Edit: automatic content assist feature was also slowing me down, so I turned it off. I just use it only when I need it by pressing CTRL + Space. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906137/disable-content-assist-in-eclipse) for details.

Answer (score 13):

Disable the startup window (called Dashboard) which downloads RSS feeds from the Spring team upon program launch: http://tux2323.blogspot.se/2010/08/eclipse-tipp-reloaded-disable-sts.html. Should you want see it you can use Help->Dashboard.

Comment: In STS 3.2 this option has moved to Window->Preferences->SpringSource->Dashboard.

Answer (score 7):

Couple of more ways to reduce the memory foot print on Eclipse/STS

1. you can right click on project and choose to close unrelated projects
2. you can try creating working sets with related projects and select only the one  you are working on, you can do this from Top Right corner(View Menu) on the  Project explorer tab
3. Youcan monitor Heapsize, from Preferences General you can check the "Show Heap Status" to show the currently used heapspace , this will show a "recycle bin" icon beside the heap value, you can click this to force Garbage collection

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with a Maven update process running for a while, every time I launch STS.

Maven tried to connect to  `http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e<your_eclipse_version>`

As per [the Jira of STS](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-2890?focusedCommentId=78471&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-78471), I changed it to

`http://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e<your_eclipse_version>`

in <kbd>Window</kbd> -> <kbd>Preferences</kbd> -> <kbd>Install/Update</kbd> -> <kbd>Available software</kbd>

And now the process is immediate.