# Disable content assist in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

How do you disable content assist in Eclipse?

I do not mind allowing it to come up when I press ctrl & space, but I do not like how it automatically comes up as I am typing. It just messes me up. For instance it, I would end up scrolling through the options when I just want to go up a line. It is getting tedious having to press escape whenever it decides to pop up.

I have found the page in the preferences for it, but I cannot seem to find out how to disable the auto-pop-up.

EDIT: I am using the application for android development. I have already disabled "auto-activation" for both Java and XML, but it does not seem to have an effect. The window will still pop up automatically.

EDIT2: I tried restarting the program after making the changes, but it still had no effect. I made sure that the option changes were still in effect, and they were still in effect.

Comment: Can you try making a new workspace and see if those settings applies there in an Android project?

Comment: @VonC, I created a new namespace, but it did not work. The way I have been testing is typing "android:", but every time  a pop up comes up after a couple seconds.

Comment: Actually, I meant workspace, not namespace.

Comment: +1 because there have been bugs in `xulrunner` that cause Eclipse to crash when content assist is active.

Answer (score 29):

This [Eclipse3.6 Help page](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_c_editor_con_assist.htm) on Content assist can help (it is for C++, but the [same idea applies for Java](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/editor/ref-preferences-content-assist.htm) on the `Java > Editor > Content Assist` preference page.):

[image]

The idea is to disable what triggers the content assist.

Comment: I already said in my original post that I know where the options are for content assist. The problem is that I have tried disabling it, but there is no effect.

Comment: @PhaZ90771, it works fine for me. Content assist disappears once i uncheck Auto-Activation!!

Comment: For some reason it isn't working for me. I tried restarting the application, but it still had no effect.

Comment: This helped me, because I stopped looking for global content assist settings and started looking at each language's specific configuration page, where I found what I was looking for (in this case, for Clojure)

Answer (score 5):

- Go to Window → Preferences.
- In the filter text search bar, type "typing".
- Go to Editor → Typing.
- Uncheck all that you don't want.

Comment: Thanks! Best answer for me since I need to work on multiple editors and the auto-completion bug me to no end!

Comment: Thanks!  This worked perfectly!   I wasn't able to find the JSP settings to stop closing double quotes, and this found it very easily.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if you did get it to disable but I was having the same trouble as you. 
I did the following:
Window > Prefrences > Content Assist
Uncheck all and hit apply

Java > Editor > Content assist > Advanced 
Uncheck all and hit apply.

Hope this works if you still haven't found an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not readily obvious and there doesn't appear to be a global option to turn it off all over the place.  This may sound obvious, but it's important to make sure to turn off Auto-Activation on all of the different structured editor types that you do not want it active on.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse Mars.1 :-
go to Window then->preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist ->Advanced -> Restore Default ->Apply and then OK.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window -> Preferences -> PHP -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Auto Activation
Untick the box "Enable auto activation"