# Eclipse : how can I disable this popup?

Tags: eclipse

I'm sorry if this question has been ask before or can be found on the net. I have no idea how do I call this popup. I have no idea of the keyword to google. I tried "popup", "dialog", "confirmation" and a lot else but didn't success.

Back to the question, I've just migrate to my development machine and did fresh install for Eclipse. After that, I copy all the setting in workspace/.metadata folder from my previous machine to the new one. Everything looks fine (theme, key bindings and else) except that I have this popup appearing whenever I press some shortcut. For example, Ctrl+Space to bring up the code assist, the following dialog appears.

[image: The anoying dialog]

This popup never appeared before in my previous machine. It is annoying since I have to hit enter once every time I press those shortcut. Do you have any idea how can I turn this off?

Best

**Note**

I don't think this popup is code assist specific issue, I brought code assist up as an example. I also got this popup when I press shortcut to

- Open Resource
- Run
- Refactor/Rename
- Add getter/setter

and 10s other shortcut too. Also, I don't have conflict shortcut. Not that I know.

Comment: This looks like the ambiguous key binding dialog - but that normally shows two or more actions for a key. Looks like something about the key bindings is confused. perhaps by something you did copying things from the old `.metadata`.

Comment: @greg-449 yes Greg, sometime, on some shortcut press, this dialog also appears with 2 (or more) actions too. But in this case) only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question may have been answered here already: [Disable content assist in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906137/disable-content-assist-in-eclipse)

Refer to the following link for the documentation on Content Assist: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_c_editor_con_assist.htm

[image: Content Assist]

The point is to disable the actions that trigger the Content Assist.

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick replay. But, this popup is not only for code assist but also my other shortcut too. For example, open resource, run, insert getter/setter and else.