# Eclipse content-assist suggests <classname>.<parameter> for generic parameter and reports error

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, content-assist

Let's say I have the following incomplete code:

```
public class Foo<Type> {
    public Foo() {
        List<Type> list = new ArrayList|
    }
}
```

where the pipe ("|") after `ArrayList` indicates the current cursor position.

Now, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and have Eclipse auto-complete the constructor call on the `ArrayList`, it generates the following line:

```
List<Type> list = new ArrayList<Foo.Type>();
```

and immediately reports an error that "Foo.Type cannot be resolved to a type".

This leaves me with a couple of questions:

Why does Eclipse include `Foo.` in the auto-completed generic parameter? Is this a bug? Is there a reason why it does this? Can it be turned off? And lastly: Why can `Foo.Type` not be resolved???

Comment: Usually generic type variables use a single letter, e.g. `<T>` instead of `<Type>` because the second form makes it look like you're referring to an actual class called `Type`.  Eclipse may have a bug and is getting confused in this case for exactly that reason. If you change to `<T>` instead, does the issue go away?

Comment: @WilliamPrice Interesting thought. Unfortunately, changing it to `T` doesn't fix the issue. Maybe I'll report it to the Eclipse bug-tracker. They might have a solution or comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can at least partially answer your question.  First, the easy one.  `Foo.Type` cannot be resolved because that would be an *inner class* named `Type` inside the `Foo` class.  In your example, there is no such inner class. Also, in your code, the symbol `Type` is really a *generic type variable*, neither the name nor a reference to any specific class.  This is easily reproducible, shown here in DrJava, and not specific to your use of Eclipse:
[image: Screenshot from DrJava showing compiler error referencing Foo.Type]

"Why does Eclipse include `Foo.`" and "Is this a bug?"  I think the answer is clearly **yes, it is a bug**, simply because there's no such thing as `Foo.Type` in your posted code and as reported by the compiler.  But as a bug, it's harder to answer the *why* part of your question without looking into the Eclipse code, or whatever code Eclipse relies upon for its autocomplete logic.  What Eclipse *should* recommend for you is simply `Type`. Again, DrJava shows that using `<Type>` compiles cleanly as expected:

[image: Screenshot from DrJava showing a clean compilation when referencing Type without any qualifier in front of it.]

As for turning this behavior off, since I'm not an Eclipse user, the best I can do at the moment is direct you to this related SO question: [Disable content assist in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906137/disable-content-assist-in-eclipse)

While I do not know whether Eclipse is actually relying on compiler type inference to provide the autocomplete suggestion, there have been a number of javac compiler inference bugs over the years, as well as reports of Eclipse behavior not matching javac.  Some of these have been javac bugs, others are probably Eclipse issues.  A search on the Web for "java type inference bug" yields plenty of hits, but at this point it's *just a guess*.  You didn't specify which version of Java you were using; it might be interesting to try the same code using different versions (JDK 6 vs 7 vs 8).

Comment: Your explanation why `Foo.Type` cannot be resolved makes sense. And I also think that this is probably a bug, so I filed a report with the Eclipse team: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=435143. Let's see what they say. If they acknowledge it, your answer was spot on and you'll get the √ ! ;)