# How to stop Eclipse from auto modifying code?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

Can anyone tell me how to turn off the auto replace/refactoring/correction feature in Eclipse specifically in Oxygen?

Let me explain my situation. I have a class `Device`.

`public class Device extends Model {}`

Now when I try to write-

`List<Device> devices = Device.findAll()`;

Eclipse replaces it to-

`List<Device> devices = Model.findAll()`;

Now I do not want that. How can I stop Eclipse from being too smart?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906137/disable-content-assist-in-eclipse I think this is what you're looking for

Comment: It is poor practice to access a static method indirectly like this.

Comment: @greg-449 I have no choice. ActiveJDBC uses this syntax :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually a "save action" that's responsible for this: 
Window -> save actions -> configure -> in the 'Member Accesses' tab, there's a 'Static accesses' section, and within it a 'change all accesses through subtypes' that you'll want to un-check to see the magic happen.

[image]

Comment: For Oxygen, the Workflow is - _Window_ --> _Preferences_ --> _Java_ --> _Editor_ --> _Save Actions_ --> _Configure_ --> _Member Accesses_ then **uncheck** the _Change all accesses through subtypes_.