# STS is so slow on any operations

Tags: java, performance, ide, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, spring-tool-suite

I'm using STS-3.6.1.RELEASE on Win 8 and its performance is killing me. Opening files, saving changes, content assist feature or organizing imports are very slow and sometimes it crushes down.

I googled about slow performance and fasting solutions. Then applied them but result is same. Here some suggestions;

1. [Why is SpringSource Tool Suite (STS) so slow? And how can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727040/why-is-springsource-tool-suite-sts-so-slow-and-how-can-i-fix-it)
2. http://philip.yurchuk.com/software/optimal-jvm-settings-for-sts/

Eclipse or Android Studio runs very well, just STS doesnt run properly. I dont know what to do. I tried anything; some .ini file settings, other STS versions (3.6.3), closing project validators etc. but same result. I think problem is on my pc because same STS version works very well with same projects on my co-worker's pc (Win 7-8, Mac).

**My pc properties and STS**

Win 8.1, i5 1.7ghz(4cpu), 64bit, 8gb ram
spring-tool-suite-3.6.1.RELEASE-e4.4-win32-x86_64

**and sts.ini file**

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
712M
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms256m
-Xmx1536m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-XX:CompileThreshold=1000
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=10
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true
```

Any suggestion or are others having similar experiences?

Answer (score 0):

Please do mem profiling of the JVM while using STS.
Try to increase the perm size to 1024M and try again.

Thnx,
Subhash

Comment: I increased the perm size but it's unstable. Sometimes it works well sometimes doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have STS as well as your workspace located on disc? Having things on a shared network drive, for example, causes STS to slow down quite often. Just a wild guess, since you said that the same STS version performs well on a different machine while having the same projects the workspace.

If nothing helps, you could try to run JVisualVM to see what is going on inside while STS is being so slow - at least to get an idea where to look for more details.

Comment: Yes, STS and workspace are located on disc not shared network drive. 

I changed ini files with new values. Sometimes it works well sometimes doesnt. I dont get what wrong is.

**changed values;**
`1768M -Xms1512m -Xmx2560m -XX:MaxPermSize=2560m`

I will try JVisualVM to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, 
i solved it by turning the build automatically option off, 
it works..
you can turn the automatic content assist off as well
but just unchecking the build autimaticall option will be enough..

you can find the option in project -> build automatically 
just uncheck it .. and you are good to go.