# Spring Tool Suite 3.9.2 + Mac High Sierra very bad performance

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, spring-tool-suite

I just bought my first Mac Book Pro (i7, SSD, 16GB RAM), I've installed Eclipse STS and realized that the performance is terrible.

For example, when I save 2 or 3 files in 5 seconds, the program crashes and after 3-4 minutes it responds again but very slowly and I have to restart it. The performance improves a lot if I turn off the `Build Automatically`...but I find it very sad.

I've been working with my old PC (i7, 8GB RAM and normal HD) and the performance is much better. I'm considering returning the Mac and buying a new PC.

Before installing STS I had installed the latest version of JDK.

My question is if there are any Mac settings missing for STS to work properly.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727040/why-is-springsource-tool-suite-sts-so-slow-and-how-can-i-fix-it) is for a much older version of STS, but disabling unnecessary validators may still help.

Comment: I am using a very similar machine with the same versions of STS and macOS and it behaves quite well on my end. So I don't think that there is anything wrong with your machine. In order to find out why the performance sucks so badly on your end, I would like to investigate this in depth. In case you are interested and willing to help a bit, please raise an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues and we can follow-up there. I am sure we can identify and solve the performance issues. It is absolutely not the way to tooling is designed to work... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/240).

Since I removed this line from `STS.ini`:

```
-Xverify:none
```

The performance has improved remarkably even with `Build Automatically` enabled.

Answer (score 0):

To my experience, STS is a heavy tool designed for Spring projects. Auto build option will only make the tool hang and system will freeze. Better you can disable that option and use the tool. There's no problem with your Max book AFAIK.